# SQL Query - Compare all rows from temp table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Rooms` and a temporary table `Room_Nums`

Columns for `Rooms` table:

```
Rooms(
 ID,
 room_name,
 max_Adults,
 max_Children
);

-- Populate
INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES (1,"Room A",2,1),(2,"Room B",2,5),(3,"Room C",3,1);
```

Temporary table:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Room_Nums;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Room_Nums(
 ID int(1),
 Adults int(2),
 Children int(2)
);

-- Populate
INSERT INTO Room_Nums VALUES (1,2,0),(2,2,5);
```

---

I want to select **only** the `Rooms` that have `max_adults` + `max_children` smaller or equal (`<=`) from all the rows in `Room_Nums` along with the ID from `Room_Nums`

**EDIT**
It's MySQL.

If `Room_Nums` has 2 rows it means I'm asking for 2 rooms that match `Adults` + `Children` ex.

```
SELECT r.room_name, rn.Adults, rn.Children, rn.ID
FROM Rooms r
     OUTER JOIN Room_Nums rn 
         ON (rn.Adults <= r.max_Adults AND rn.Children <= r.max_Children )
```

**EDIT 2**
Asking for:

- 1 Room: 2 Adults & 0 Children
- 1 Room: 2 Adults & 5 Children

The result should be:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Room Name | Adults | Children | Room_Nums.ID |
-----------------------------------------------
| Room A    |   2    |    0     |    1         |
-----------------------------------------------
| Room B    |   2    |    5     |    1         |
-----------------------------------------------
| Room B    |   2    |    5     |    2         |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Show empty result if it can't find a row from `Room_Nums`.

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server (i.e., Microsoft SQL Server)?  Syntax implies MySQL.

Comment: please further explain this _smaller or equal (<=) from all the rows_

Comment: Let say that you have a room (4, "Room D', 1, 0). What is an expected output?

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag because the syntax suggests MySQL.

Comment: Do you need a temporary table (MySQL will create them if it needs to for large queries.... you should really try views)

Comment: How else would I select the Room numbers? I'm using the temp table as a reference, although I've made it work by adding EXISTS but it looks messy. With VIEWS I'm not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Although, it is not quite clear, what is meant by "all the rows", maybe this will work

```
 Select room_name,  max_adults + max_children, Room_nums.ID
 from Rooms 
 left join Room_nums 
 on Rooms.id=Room_nums.id 
 WHERE max_adults + max_children <= (select min(adults + children) from Room_nums);
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking, I'm not comparing the ID's, edited my question again for more clarification.